# Why is reciprocal correct here? She loves him so much, but I am not sure it is (mutual/reciprocal)

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I have come across this example in an exercise - She loves him so much, but I am not sure it is (mutual/reciprocal). I looked into both words' definitions and could not say why mutual is incorrect here.

Answer (score 1):

We already know that she loves him so much. So when we say 'not sure if it is mutual,' we are implying that we are not sure about the first part of the sentence either. So I feel reciprocal would fit in better as it shows that we are only not sure if she is also loved by him.

This is my perception and I would have rather put it as a comment but I can't. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helps!